# True notation for sin squared

Tags: matlab, trigonometry

I need to compute something like this in Matlab:

> sin<sup>4</sup>(x)

and no

> (sin(x))^4

But when I try `sin^4(x)`, Matlab gives an error.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sin(x).^4
```

You need to use the [element wise](http://www.glue.umd.edu/afs/glue.umd.edu/system/info/olh/Numerical/Matlab_Matrix_Manipulation_Software/Matrix_Vector_Operations/elementwise) power operator